# Intermittent error with imgur when uploading images?

Tags: support, images, imgur

I just tried to upload an image as part of answering a question and I get a placeholder indicating that the image isn't present;

[image]

If I try and access the image using its URL directly I get the following;

[image]

Doing a bit of a further lookup on the IP address reported in this error message (since it changes with each request), these don't even seem to be IP addresses that are related to me at all;

```
IP Address        198.7.20.199 
Host              198-7-20-199.edgecastcdn.net 
Location          US US, United States 
City              Santa Monica, CA 90405 
Organization      EdgeCast Networks
```

Is this just me experiencing this issue or is this a more general issue with imgur or stackexchange linking to imgur?

Comment: I get this. Local to GB?

Comment: No, Blem and Martin got them as well

Comment: Local to EU then?

Comment: perhaps, how many Americans do you know on chat at the moment?

Comment: I was able to upload image in [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10110399#10110399), a couple of min later it failed in [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10110425#10110425), I am located in Denmark.

Comment: @tombull89 now why couldn't I find that post when I searched for it? hmmm?